# getting $_GET string from http://localhost/path1/path2?get3=value

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I will try not to make this too complicated. :)
Basically, I have converted my links with .htaccess to convert

```
http://www.link.com?get1=path1&get2=path2
```

to

```
http://www.link.com/path1/path2
```

so basically, I want to know if i converted my links to be like that, would it still be possible to use the question mark GET in the link like this:

```
link.com/path1/path2?get3=path3
```

if yes, how do i retrieve that `$_GET["get3"]` value?
Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
this is how the htaccess was modified
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ home.php?get1=$1&get2=$2

Comment: This -> `http://www.link.com/path1/path2` is nothing but `http://www.link.com?get1=path1&get2=path2` so yes, you `$_GET[]` will work and it has to

Comment: [RTFM](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Just add `[QSA]` to your rewrite rule.

Comment: Thanks RTFM for that! it does work after adding [QSA] to the end of the rewrite rule. Thanks others for the answers too.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you did it, if you used redirect, then you wont see the `$_GET` params, but i think that if you are trying to hide the parameters, maybe `$_POST` is what you are looking for